# best performance for 1080p video in flash (standalone projector)

Tags: actionscript-3, projector

i need to convert a little flash site which does fullscreen video to a standalone-projector
the projector will run in windows 7 or xp and has to playback videos at 1080p

does anyone here have experiences how to get the best performance out of this?
hardware acceleration seems to be possible now ?

best regards and thanks for all input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flash.media.StageVideo` is hardware accelerated playback reducing load on cpu:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html

> The H.264 codec is stage video's best friend; using this will ensure
>   you get full GPU acceleration from video decoding to rendering. With
>   this approach, no read-back (sending the data from the GPU to the CPU)
>   is required to composite the video frames in the display list anymore.
>   The YUV 4:2:0 formatted video frames are converted to RGB through a
>   GPU shader (DirectX9 or OpenGL) and blitted onscreen. As a result, you
>   will see higher pixel fidelity and some reduction in CPU and memory
>   usage.

From that link above, Thibault Imbert has an example implementation of stage video:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.FullScreenEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.StageVideoAvailabilityEvent;
    import flash.events.StageVideoEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.events.VideoEvent;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.media.SoundTransform;
    import flash.media.StageVideo;
    import flash.media.StageVideoAvailability;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    /**
     * 
     * @author Thibault Imbert
     * 
     */ 
    [SWF(frameRate="1", backgroundColor="#000000")]
    public class SimpleStageVideo extends Sprite
    {
        private static const FILE_NAME:String = "video-file.mov";
        private static const INTERVAL:Number = 500;
        private static const BORDER:Number = 20;

        private var legend:TextField = new TextField();
        private var sv:StageVideo;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var ns:NetStream;
        private var rc:Rectangle;
        private var video:Video;
        private var thumb:Shape;
        private var interactiveThumb:Sprite;
        private var totalTime:Number;

        private var videoWidth:int;
        private var videoHeight:int;
        private var outputBuffer:String = new String();
        private var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, BORDER);
        private var videoRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        private var gotStage:Boolean;
        private var stageVideoInUse:Boolean;
        private var classicVideoInUse:Boolean;
        private var accelerationType:String;
        private var infos:String = new String();
        private var available:Boolean;
        private var inited:Boolean;
        private var played:Boolean;
        private var container:Sprite;

        /**
         * 
         * 
         */     
        public function SimpleStageVideo()
        {
            // Make sure the app is visible and stage available
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
        {
            // Scaling
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            legend.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

            // Debug infos
            legend.multiline = true;
            legend.background = true;
            legend.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            addChild(legend);

            // Thumb seek Bar
            thumb = new Shape();

            interactiveThumb = new Sprite();
            interactiveThumb.addChild(thumb);
            addChild(interactiveThumb);

            // Connections
            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);
            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
            ns.client = this;

            // Screen
            video = new Video();
            video.smoothing = true;

            // Video Events
            // the StageVideoEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_STATE informs you if StageVideo is available or not
            stage.addEventListener(StageVideoAvailabilityEvent.STAGE_VIDEO_AVAILABILITY, onStageVideoState);
            // in case of fallback to Video, we listen to the VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE event to handle resize properly and know about the acceleration mode running
            video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, videoStateChange);

            // Input Events
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,  onResize);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onNetStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            if ( event.info == "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" )
                legend.text = "Video file passed, not available!";
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onFrame(event:Event):void 
        {
            var ratio:Number = (ns.time / totalTime) * (stage.stageWidth - (BORDER << 1));
            rect.width = ratio;
            thumb.graphics.clear();
            thumb.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
            thumb.graphics.drawRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);   
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if ( event.stageY >= interactiveThumb.y - BORDER && event.stageX <= stage.stageWidth - BORDER )
            {
                var seekTime:Number = (stage.mouseX - BORDER) * ( totalTime / (stage.stageWidth - (BORDER << 1) ) );
                ns.seek( seekTime );    
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {   
            if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.O )
            {
                if ( available )
                    // We toggle the StageVideo on and off (fallback to Video and back to StageVideo)
                    toggleStageVideo(inited=!inited);

            } else if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.F )
            {
                stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
            } else if ( event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE )
            {
                ns.togglePause();
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param width
         * @param height
         * @return 
         * 
         */     
        private function getVideoRect(width:uint, height:uint):Rectangle
        {   
            var videoWidth:uint = width;
            var videoHeight:uint = height;
            var scaling:Number = Math.min ( stage.stageWidth / videoWidth, stage.stageHeight / videoHeight );

            videoWidth *= scaling, videoHeight *= scaling;

            var posX:uint = stage.stageWidth - videoWidth >> 1;
            var posY:uint = stage.stageHeight - videoHeight >> 1;

            videoRect.x = posX;
            videoRect.y = posY;
            videoRect.width = videoWidth;
            videoRect.height = videoHeight;

            return videoRect;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         */     
        private function resize ():void
        {   
            if ( stageVideoInUse )
            {
                // Get the Viewport viewable rectangle
                rc = getVideoRect(sv.videoWidth, sv.videoHeight);
                // set the StageVideo size using the viewPort property
                sv.viewPort = rc;
            } else 
            {
                // Get the Viewport viewable rectangle
                rc = getVideoRect(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
                // Set the Video object size
                video.width = rc.width;
                video.height = rc.height;
                video.x = rc.x, video.y = rc.y;
            }

            interactiveThumb.x = BORDER, interactiveThumb.y = stage.stageHeight - (BORDER << 1);
            legend.text = infos;
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param evt
         * 
         */     
        public function onMetaData ( evt:Object ):void
        {
            totalTime = evt.duration;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onStageVideoState(event:StageVideoAvailabilityEvent):void
        {   
            // Detect if StageVideo is available and decide what to do in toggleStageVideo
            toggleStageVideo(available = inited = (event.availability == StageVideoAvailability.AVAILABLE));
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param on
         * 
         */     
        private function toggleStageVideo(on:Boolean):void
        {   
            infos = "StageVideo Running (Direct path) : " + on + "\n";

            // If we choose StageVideo we attach the NetStream to StageVideo
            if (on) 
            {
                stageVideoInUse = true;
                if ( sv == null )
                {
                    sv = stage.stageVideos[0];
                    sv.addEventListener(StageVideoEvent.RENDER_STATE, stageVideoStateChange);
                }
                sv.attachNetStream(ns);
                if (classicVideoInUse)
                {
                    // If we use StageVideo, we just remove from the display list the Video object to avoid covering the StageVideo object (always in the background)
                    stage.removeChild ( video );
                    classicVideoInUse = false;
                }
            } else 
            {
                // Otherwise we attach it to a Video object
                if (stageVideoInUse)
                    stageVideoInUse = false;
                classicVideoInUse = true;
                video.attachNetStream(ns);
                stage.addChildAt(video, 0);
            }

            if ( !played ) 
            {
                played = true;
                ns.play(FILE_NAME);
            }
        } 

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function onResize(event:Event):void
        {
            resize();       
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function stageVideoStateChange(event:StageVideoEvent):void
        {   
            infos += "StageVideoEvent received\n";
            infos += "Render State : " + event.status + "\n";
            resize();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param event
         * 
         */     
        private function videoStateChange(event:VideoEvent):void
        {   
            infos += "VideoEvent received\n";
            infos += "Render State : " + event.status + "\n";
            resize();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the best video you want to use the new [StageVideo](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html) in order to use hardware acceleration.  The site will need to be as3 and StageVideo runs under the normal flash stage so you will need to hide any flash elements other then your controls while the video is playing.  Also I would consider using AIR instead of the projector method for packaging the files into a self-contained app.

Comment: hello, and thanks. why would you prefer air over projector? i'd rather not deal with this whole runtime update and install procedure.

Comment: You can use air as a captive runtime: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html  you can also now do this from within Flash in the publish settings as well. I think starting with flash CS 5.5 - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wpi00UAoFjE